# Unity PC version is totally different from Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a racing game with Unity for PC and Android. However, after I have built an apk and played it on Android, many things had changed and it was totally different from PC version. For example, in PC version, when the car goes backward, there will be a message "wrong way" show and the message will disappear when the car falls from the track. But in Android version, the message will still show even the player falls from the track.

Besides, the car turn faster in PC version than in Android. All scripts are the same but only on different platform. What would the problem be? I'm really confused. Any reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your questions there are 2 issues

1) Message not disappear after car fall back to original track on android device
  Answer : this is because of missing plugin. Please check all plugins import properly and also check your logs. There might be some error. I faced this type of issue and my issue was because I import ads SDK not in proper way.

2) Speed of the car is different. 
 Answer: For resolving this type of issue you have to add device check. Like for turning different code on mobile devices and different on pc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try them asap.

Answer (score 0):

Your second Problem could be caused by not using [deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html), or you are using it on some parts of your calculations and forgot it when calculating the turn rate.

As your game will run on a different FPS on PC/Android it is important to substract out that difference and make your game frame independend.

Further Reading on DeltaTime: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/296336/timedeltatime.html

Comment: Thanks! It's a great reference to me!